# ViewData coming up as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this test page. This is the action method.

```
public ActionResult TestView()
{
    ViewData["Test"] = "1";
    return View("TestView");
}
```

In TestView.cshtml, I have this line of code

```
@ViewData["Test"]
```

It is coming up as null, it is not printing the "1".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: it should work fine. Are you sure you are checking the correct view  and the action method is GET type ?

Comment: I have [HttpGet] attribute above the action method. I am checking the correct view. I know the code is pretty straight forward, but I must be missing something.

Comment: Well, I was not rebuilding the project :-) That's what was missing. Don't I feel stupid.

Comment: @SKT even your code works find in my project found nothing wrong. do you have Action/Result filters in your project? please have a look into those as well.

Answer (score 1):

MV3 have ViewBag as a new object that can hold the dynamic properties as Key/Value pair.

So you can directly assign a property using ViewBag. For e.g. -

In your action in controller you can write something like

```
ViewBag.Message = "1";
```

Now to retrieve the value you can write in your .cshtml

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
```